# Split sentences string into new line properly (JAVA)

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I want to split sentence (thai language) in proper way in pdf report (by JAVA) Please see my code below as.

```
def document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Constants.FILE));
document.open()
document.setMargins(1,1,1,1);
Font fontSarabunBold = new Font(BaseFont.createFont("fonts/THSarabun Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED));
Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(20, "ณ ป่าใหญ่แห่งหนึ่ง มีกระต่ายตัวหนึ่งมั่นใจในความเร็วของฝีเท้าตัวเองมาก และมักพูดโม้โอ้อวดว่าไม่มีใครเทียบเทียมได้ จนวันหนึ่งเจ้ากระต่ายได้พบกับเต่าที่กำลังเดินต้วมเตี้ยมผ่านมา เมื่อเห็นดังนั้น เจ้ากระต่ายก็หัวเราะเยาะและพูดล้อเลียนว่า นี่เจ้าเต่า มัวแต่เดินอืดอาดอย่างนี้ แล้วเมื่อไรจะถึงบ้านกันล่ะเนี่ย ต่อให้เจ้าเดินนำหน้าไปก่อนครึ่งวัน ข้ายังตามเจ้าทันเลย", fontSarabunBold)
document.add(para1);
document.close()
```

This is result.
[image]

It seems that program split sentence by space.

But I want to get sentences which are spitted in proper way same as I typed sentences in Microsoft Word.

This is expected result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bell,in Paragraph writing PdfWriter , if sentence is not fitting in one line, it automatically move to next line after space as  our formal language sentences are completed by dot "." , so there possible way to do this work .

1)  Assign complete sentence to   para1 = new Paragraph(20,"this is sentence.");
and then move to next line and assign new paragraph.